# Firefox disable cache devtools inline javascript and ajax innerhtml

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, innerhtml, disable

I am loading a second HTML page into a parent page container div via a JavaScript Ajax callback via innerhtml. The issue I have is the caching of the inner HTML content loaded into the container div. This page contains inline JavaScript. I have cache disabled in devtools settings. The only way I've found to reload both the parent page and the container page with updated js is to restart Firefox.

In-line JavaScript is only a dozen or so lines so would prefer not to create a separate JS script file if possible.

Any ideas about how to force a reload of the entire page including the container ?
Thanks
Paul

I have disabled the cache in dev tools. Multiple reloading of the page in the debugger still shows the outdated in-line JavaScript. I am using debugger in the js to detect changes and can see page not updated after edit.

Comment: GET requests made via AJAX can get cached quite "hard" by browsers (although I am surprised the dev tools setting does not help circumvent that.) You could try switching to POST instead (of the URL you are loading allows for that); or append a random query string parameter as a "cache buster."

Comment: Thanks. Generally its not an issue but very annoying yesterday in testing. I am using pretty urls so the query string will mess up that and the router. I amgoing to give this a try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data